# Country and External IP Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ip, wan

I created a script based on what I could find on the INTERNET and some bash tutorials, that will show me my external IP and the country it's located in.

#

Script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wanip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com);
echo "$wanip" > /root/Documents/filewanip;
iplist="/root/Documents/filewanip"

while read IP;do
whois "$IP"
done < "$iplist" | grep "country" >geoloc
cat geoloc filewanip
rm filewanip geoloc
```

#

Output looks like this:
country:        Holland
183.64.132.80

#

Problem is that I don't want to use files to do this as file structure obviously changes from system to system. 
How can I make it in an elegant way so the check is made and stored into a variable(s) and then displayed directly into the shell?

John Connor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, your goal is to eliminate the use of temporary files.  In that case:

```
#!/bin/bash
wanip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com);
echo "$wanip" | while read ip; do
    echo "$ip $(whois "$ip" | awk ' /[Cc]ountry/{print $2}')"
done
```

The above was written as if `dig` returns more than one address for your IP.  If that is not the case, then the `while` loop is superfluous.

If you are only expecting one IP, then:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com);
echo "$ip $(whois "$ip" | awk ' /[Cc]ountry/{print $2}')"
```

Notes:

- I converted IP to ip because it is best practices to use lower or mixed case names for your shell variables.
- My `whois` returns a line with Country, not country.  So, I made the search for country case insensitive.

Comment: John1024 this is exactly what I needed. You sir deserve a cookie!
 I need to start learning awk and sed, postponing it for some time now.

Can't up your vote damn, I'm to low in rank :(